# Pagelets in PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

Can we dynamically pass parameters for a Pagelet in tools 8.50? I am looking to create dashboards using Pagelets where the user needs to pass parameters on the fly

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many who'll be able to answer this as Tools 8.50 won't be available to those outside Oracle until Sept/Oct this year.